# How to use inner product to find angle? Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let C[0, π] denote the set of real-valued continuous functions on [0, π].
Define an inner product on C[0, π] by
(f, g)C[0,π] ≡ $$\int_0^π f(x)g(x)dx$$.
Use this inner product to determine the angle between sin x and x.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^\pi f(x)g(x)\,dx,$$ and the formula for the angle between two elements $u, v$ in an inner product space $V$ is given by $$\cos\theta = {\langle u, v\rangle\over\|u\|\|v\|}.$$ Observe that if $u = \sin(x)$ and $v = x$, then $$\|u\|^2 = {\langle u,u\rangle} = {\int_0^\pi\sin^2(x)\,dx} = {\pi/2},$$ $$\|v\|^2 = \langle v, v\rangle = \int_0^\pi x^2\,dx = {\pi^3\over3}.$$ I leave it to you to compute the remainder of the parts and apply inverse cosine to determine the angle.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\cos\theta=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}\cdot\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}}$$